# I'm trying to create svg arrow with css for up arrow and down arrow with animations but not able to make up arrow

Tags: html, css, svg-filters

I'm trying to make up an arrow with CSS using SVG but not able to make it. I used this code pen https://codepen.io/postor/pen/mskxI to create down arrow which works fine

```html
<svg className="arrows">
  <path className="a1" d="M0 0 L30 32 L60 0"></path>
  <path className="a2" d="M0 20 L30 52 L60 20"></path>
  <path className="a3" d="M0 40 L30 72 L60 40"></path>
</svg>
```

But I'm not able to make up arrow with the same effect any help?

Comment: Can you show what you have tried and what obstacle is holding you back? Also your question makes it seem like you wrote that codepen when you didn't, you may want to re-word your question.

Comment: yea i used that code pen sorry not write myself...i dont know how to make up arrows with existing code from the code pen @SydneyY

Comment: @SydneyY im messing around changing the d value in the above code snipppet to make up arrow

Comment: @dave https://codepen.io/ArnisLapsa/pen/KKpZpqX

Comment: @dave https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_path.asp